# Selenium IDE - Slow is too fast

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I want to create tests with Selenium IDE for SharePoint 2010. I set the control in Selenium IDE to slow, but it is often to fast and the test fails because javascripts are loading etc.

Is there a way to slow down the script?

Comment: I know this isn't helpful but, should you not be asking how you can speed up your page?

Comment: No sorry, that is not possible ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from placing `pause(waitTime)` between your statements, I would recommend to transition the IDE scripts to Selenium RC and use the `selenium.setSpeed("milliseconds");` statement (java) to control the execution speed.

Answer (score 4):

I had best results using functions like *waitForElementPresent* or *waitForVisible*. This way you can just wait for specific element you want to work with. For example if you click link Next and want to click Previous when page reloads, instead of writing andWait abbreviation you could use something like this:

```
waitForElementPresent(Previous)
click(Previous)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pauses means your tests are going to pass while your server is under the same load but they will start failing as soon as your server is under heavier load. 
You should use the clickAndWait command, which waits for the next page to load before continuing with anymore commands.

> click/clickAndWait - performs a click operation, and optionally waits for a new page to load.
>
> waitForPageToLoad - pauses execution until an expected new page loads. Called automatically when clickAndWait is used.

[Reference](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#commonly-used-selenium-commands)

Answer (score 0):

Put this after your click commands: **pause(length of time in ms)**

For example:

```
pause(1000)
```

This pauses for 1 second. Start with a higher value until it works, then work your way down to find the smallest possible pause.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the speed of each step with Selenium IDE

Command    Target
setSpeed   65           (set the speed of item)
setSpeed   0            (reset the speed)